# Fullcalendar initialization

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have a problem with Fullcalendar initialization, or to be more precise when I load the page only the top part, header part of the calendar is shown, whilst the rest of it is invisible until I click on inspect or change the size of the screen.

[image]

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

This is HTML:

```
<div class="profile-content" id="box6">
<div class="profile-schedule">
    <h2 class="profile-schedule-title">Schedule</h2>
    <div id="calendar"></div>
</div>
```

And here is the JS part

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek'
        },
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        expandRows: true,
        navLinks: true,
        editable: true,
        dragScroll: true,
        eventColor: '#E43D50',
        events: [{
                title: 'Clyde Stokes',
                start: '2022-07-04',
                display: 'background',
                color: '#E43D50'
            },
            {
                title: 'Lunch',
                start: '2022-07-12T12:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Conference',
                start: '2022-07-11',
                end: '2022-07-13',
                color: 'rgba(255,255,255, 0.04)' // override!
            }
        ]
    });
    calendar.render();
});
```

Comment: your code seems to work as it is: https://jsfiddle.net/4026xs8g/2/

Comment: This way put, yes. Could it be a problem because the calendar is part of the custom navigation, where in the sidebar I have links that open different components on the right side, one of the components being calendar. When the page is reloaded it opens up on a first component which is display block, whilst the others are display none until clicked? Does it maybe have anything to do with event listener or handler?

Comment: yes, that could be the reason, lots of components behave strangely when the html element they rely upon is not shown at first / lazy loaded and other scenarios.

Comment: a dirty hack could be manually triggering the window::resize event right after rendering the calendar: `calendar.render(); window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));` but if the tab is still not switched I don't think it's going to work

Comment: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/vYRmEbx - your code works, as shown. I'd guess there's some issue outside this, as others have said. Before we can help you properly, you'll need to provide a [mre] of the issue in your question. At a guess, if the calendar is initially hidden when the page loads, or is hidden at a later time, then you'll need to run `calendar.render()` after the element in which it's hidden is shown again. Otherwise it won't display properly.